# Kindle Fire HD 8 - cannot load app

Tags: amazon-kindle-fire-hd

I have a Kindle Fire HD 8 (7th Gen), Kids Edition. Fire OS 5.6.0.1

The tablet has Amazon FreeTime installed for my son. I have installed Google Play Store on the tablet. I have downloaded a game (BeyBlade Burst) that I can play in standard profile. However, I cannot load it in the FreeTime profile.

I have searched in the 'Add Content' and the game is not listed under "games & apps" I set the 'Smart Filters' to off to allow the game parameters. However, it still doesn't show up in the FreeTime profile.

How can I enable this game in the FreeTime profile?